# How to convert a character into a number

Tags: c

I have a homework problem. It requires me to convert a word into uppercase and several characters have to be converted to decimal for example : 
"Hello my NamE is FeLix" --> "H3LL0 MY N4M3 15 F3L1X". So, these characters had to be converted :

```
I = 1
S = 5
E = 3
O = 0 
A = 4
etc.
```

How to convert it? I already tried to convert it to capslock but i cannot convert it into decimal.

I already tried to convert the words into uppercase, but have no idea how to convert the character into numbers.

```
int main()
    {
        char sentence[200];
        int sentencelength = strlen(sentence);

    // Ambil data user
    scanf("%s",&sentence); getchar();

    // Cek satu persatu pake for
    for (int i= 1; i <= sentencelength; i++) {
        if(sentence[i] >= 'a' && sentence[i] <= 'z') {
            char uppercase = sentence[i] + 'A' - 'a';
            printf("%c",uppercase);
        }
    }

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

There is no error, but I just have no idea how to convert it.

Comment: http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html

Comment: Do you know `if`?

Comment: You are calculating `sentencelength` before you read the `sentence`. And your loop indices are off by one: In C, array indices atart at 0.

Comment: If you want to get fancy you can create a translation table (an array with 256 values, indexed with the unsigned char value, containing the desired output character). That'd be fastest without any branches and covers your uppercase translation in one go as well.

Comment: `char uppercase = sentence[i] + 'A' - 'a';` Ouch. That is not guaranteed to work.  This is:  `int uppercase = toupper( ( unsigned char ) sentence[ i ] );`  Note the return value is an `int`.  You can truncate that down to a `char` if you prefer.  Note also that `toupper()` takes an `int` as its argument.  If you're not careful, a `signed char` value can be improperly converted, so the cast to `unsigned char` is needed (or make `sentence` an `unsigned char` array).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `switch` as below.

```
switch(uppercase ) {
   case 'I':
      uppercase = '1';
   break;

   case 'S':
      uppercase = '5';
   break;

   case 'E':
      uppercase = '3';
   break;

   …

  }
```

Comment: Yeah, a switch is probably better than an if-else chain.

Comment: where should i put the print? after switch?

Comment: @FelixPrima Before you print the string, the above code is just an example.

Comment: thanks a lot, but i have a problem here, it cannot print the 'space'. for example : Hi Im fEliX --> H11MF3L1X. how can i solve that?

Comment: @FelixPrima Please ask different question with updated code.

Answer (score 1):

C arrays start at index 0, not 1, so change the `for` loop bounds to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < sentencelength; i++) {
```

You can use `toupper` (declared by `#include <ctype.h>`) to convert a character from lowercase to uppercase, leaving non-alphabetic characters alone. It is only defined for values representable by an `unsigned char` or for the value `EOF`.

```
        char l33t = sentence[i];
        if (l33t == (unsigned char)l33t)
            l33t = toupper(l33t);
```

You can use a `switch` statement to replace certain uppercase letters with digits:

```
        switch (l33t) {
        case 'I':
            l33t = '1';
            break;
        case 'S':
            l33t = '5';
            break;
        case 'E':
            l33t = '3';
            break;
        case 'O':
            l33t = '0';
            break;
        case 'A':
            l33t = '4';
            break;
        }
```

---

Rather than using `scanf` to read a whole word of input into a buffer, an alternative  is to read the input a character at a time. Here is an example program that behaves as a filter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static int convert(int ch)
{
    if (ch  == (unsigned char)ch)
        ch = toupper(ch);
    switch (ch) {
    case 'I': ch = '1'; break;
    case 'S': ch = '5'; break;
    case 'E': ch = '3'; break;
    case 'O': ch = '0'; break;
    case 'A': ch = '4'; break;
    }
    return ch;
}

int main(void)
{
    int ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ch = convert(ch);
        putchar(ch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above will convert the whole input until it sees end-of-file.  To terminate after a single line, just add a check for a newline character to break out of the `while` loop.

Comment: thanks a lot, but i have a problem here, it cannot print the 'space'. for example : Hi Im fEliX --> H11MF3L1X. how can i solve that?

Comment: @FelixPrima Well `scanf("%s", sentence);` only reads a single word. There isn't actually any need to read in whole words. You can read and process the characters one-by-one, as in the example at the end of my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

create an array of characters: [4BCD3F....Z]
and an array of sources: [abcd...z]

run on your string, replace each character found in index I with the same character in the first array, if it's not found return the character as is.

crude, simple, works

Also, if someone complain on the calculation complexity, since you have fixed number of letters in the arrays A to Z , the complexity is O(N*M) when M is const, hence O(N) anyway